# php-fpm: ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (48)

Tags: php, nginx, server

I have a small problem with my local server running with php-fpm and nginx.

I can't run php-fpm it returns an error (the title).

And when I type the command `sudo lsof -i :9000` I get this (server/network is not my cup of tea):

```
php-fpm   47 root    8u  IPv4 0x619bafbaac199241      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm  262 _www    9u  IPv4 0x619bafbaac199241      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm  263 _www    9u  IPv4 0x619bafbaac199241      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm 2623 _www    9u  IPv4 0x619bafbaac199241      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
```

configuration file /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php-fpm.conf test is successful

`sudo php-fpm -t` returns:

`NOTICE: configuration file /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php-fpm.conf test is successful`

Is this normal? If not how can I get ride of it?

Comment: can you please describe what your problem is? you can't start php-fpm because it's already running...

Comment: for sure it's apache which taking the port: service apache2 stop

Comment: this question has gone obsolete, I'm facing same issue. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5):

The question has been asked exactly a year ago but, if someone bumps to this question, like me. Here's what worked for me (on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6):

1. Executed `brew services list` in the terminal, which gave following output:

   ```sh
   Name       Status  User  Plist
   nginx      started foo   /Users/foo/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
   php        started root  /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
   postgresql stopped            
   redis      stopped
   ```
2. From the above output, got to know that user for php-fpm wasn't *foo*. So, stopped the service, using: `sudo brew services stop php`.
3. And finally, restarted php for *foo*, using: `brew services restart php`.

Everything worked fine after following above steps. **The main cause of the issue was port '9000' was already under use by *root* php process and thus, *foo* php process didn't initialise.**

Comment: For me this was php 7.4 installed via `brew install php`. I did a `brew remove php --force` and installed `brew install php@7.2` (along with `brew unlink php && brew link php@7.2 --force --overwrite`) and did a restart and it went away...

Comment: note that its `brew services` not service

Answer (score 1):

On SUSE 15.4 I found my issue to be with apparmor. I am installing Zabbix and kept getting:

```
ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php-fpm/zabbix-php-fpm.sock': Permission denied (13)
```

I tried CHOWN, moved the location of the sock file, and tried renaming the sock file, nothing worked. I finally ran a tail on /var/log/audit.d/audit and found this msg:

```
apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="php-fpm" name="/run/php-fpm/zabbix-php-fpm.sock" pid=11239 comm="php-fpm" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

With a little more digging I found:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm
```

and changed one line:

```
@{run}/php{,-fpm}/php*-fpm.sock rwlk,
```

and changed it to:

```
@{run}/php{,-fpm}/*php*-fpm.sock rwlk,
```

huped the apparmour service and like #! it worked.

Hope this helps as I have wasted several hours on this issue....